# How to show image portfolio on click in jquery

Tags: jquery, portfolio

I have many projects listed and each project has many images. On project page I am displaying project feature image and its description. Now I want that when I click on feature image of any project it should show only its images in slider form like Fancybox.

Is there any Jquery plugin or code??

This is my link:

http://tgwebdemos.com/ferrutti/projects.php

Thanks

Comment: it is better to include relevant code to OP than a link.

Comment: I don't have any code yet.